# Does anyone have an example of drawing an object outside the renderer class?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, opengl-es, rendering

I'm learning OpenGL ES for android, but i'm a tiny bit confused.

In the examples I've seen the drawing of an object, let's say a square is done in the renderer via:

```
public class MainRender implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private Square      square;     // the square
private Context     context;

/** Constructor to set the handed over context */
public MainRender(Context context) {
    this.context = context;

    // initialise the square
    this.square = new Square();
}


    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // clear Screen and Depth Buffer
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
                square.draw(gl); 
                    }
```

This is great and all, but my whole point for doing this is to separate most of the logic from the rendering process...

So i'm not comfortable with instantiating the Square instance inside the renderer class.
I know that a safe way to communicate between threads is by using queueEvent(), but the examples I've seen only queue events that alter, rotate, or translate an existing class in renderer, and i'm unable to figure out by myself how to draw something instantiated in another thread (eventually dynamically through a hashmap would be ideal) but I need an example of how to do it at all, or if it's possible?

-Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way to communicate between other threads in your app and your GL thread / renderer is to keep your instance of your renderer to hand in your activity:

```
public class stackoverflowTest extends Activity {

GLSurfaceView glSurface;
MyRenderer myRenderer;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    glSurface = (GLSurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.glSurfaceView1);

    myRenderer = new MyRenderer();        

    glSurface.setRenderer(myRenderer);

    Square mySquare = new Square();
    myRenderer.addSquareToScene(mySquare);

}
}
```

and then in your renderer

```
public class MyRenderer implements Renderer {

private Vector<Square> scene;
private Vector<Square> bufferedSquaresToAddToScene

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    while(bufferedSquaresToAddToScene.size()>0){
        scene.add(bufferedSquaresToAddToScene.remove(0));
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<scene.size();i++){
        scene.get(i).draw(gl);
    }

}

public void addSquareToScene(Square square){
    bufferedSquaresToAddToScene.add(square);
}
}
```

To communicate back in the other direction, it is a bit harder for non-UI threads, but to the UI/main thread you can just use [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html)

And yes, it should be fairly easy to do a hashmap instead of a vector so you don't load in duplicate squares

[As for confusion...](http://www.anddev.org/post107733.html#p107733)